# How to access object properties in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object

My php code is below:

```
$data['details'] = $this->category_model->edit_category($id);
print "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;
```

When I am using print my output is:

```
Array
 (
   [details] => stdClass Object
   (
        [id] => 31
        [c_parent_id] => 3
        [c_name] => Sandles
    )

  )
```

I want to access "c_name". How to access it?

Comment: try this one $data['details']->c_name

Comment: thnx it worked..!!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: @ShashankGaurav I added my answer way to do it through view.

Comment: don't be discouraged by all the people who downvoted you. that said - work through the tutorial in the codeigniter manual to learn the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print the value:

```
echo $data['details']->c_name;
```

Comment: No problem, but I want to advise you to search for the answer first. A search like "How to get a object value - PHP" will get you many hits that will tell you the answer. This is also the reason why you get so many downvotes. This question has been asked many times over.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $data['details']->c_name; would give value of c_name
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to get variable from controller to view

Filename: Example.php

```
<?php

class Example extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('category_model');
    }

    public function index(){
        $data['details'] = $this->category_model->edit_category($id);
        $this->load->view('details_view', $data);
    }

}
```

On View

```
<?php echo $details->c_name;?>
```